# Aggregation does not working in Mongoose with Match and Group

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm coding an application using AngularJS, NodeJS and Mongoose.
Now, i'm doing a chart and I need to return some data passsing some parameters.
But the aggregation does not work. I have this query working in MongoDB:

```
var user = db.getCollection('users').find(
{profile: "SUPERVISOR"},{_id: 1}).map(function(u){return u._id;}
)

db.getCollection("visitas").aggregate(
    { '$match':
     { createdAt:
       { '$gte': ISODate('2015-01-10T00:00:00.000Z'),
         '$lt': ISODate('2015-07-01T00:00:00.000Z') } } }, { '$group':
     { _id: { usuario: user, dia: [Object] },
      visitas: { '$sum': 1 } } }
)
```

When I try to run the same query in my application using Mongoose, the query does not work. The problem i've seen is that the comma between MATCH and GROUP is disapearing. When i try to search with only group or match, the query works. Someone can help me? This is the application code:

```
 .then(function (listaUsuarios){
           var argsVisit;
          console.log({ $match : { "createdAt" : { $gte: "2015-01-10T00:00:00.000Z", $lt: "2015-07-01T00:00:00.000Z"  }} },
                  { $group : { _id : { "usuario" : listaUsuarios , "dia" : { $dayOfMonth : "$createdAt" } }, "visitas" : { $sum : 1 } } });

          Visita.aggregate({ $match : { "createdAt" : { $gte: "2015-01-10T00:00:00.000Z", $lt: "2015-07-01T00:00:00.000Z"  }} },
                  { $group : { _id : { "usuario" : listaUsuarios , "dia" : { $dayOfMonth : "$createdAt" } }, "visitas" : { $sum : 1 } } })
            .exec(function (err, results) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Erro!!!");
                        deferredDados.reject({
                            error: 500,
                            message: 'Erro buscando Visita, erro: '+err
                        });
                    } else {
                        if (!results || results.length == 0) {
                            console.log("Sem retorno!!!");
                            deferredDados.resolve( [0,0,0,0,0,0,0] ); //Tudo zerado poruqe não há retorno.
                            //deferredDados.resolve(0);

                            deferredDados.reject({
                                error: 500,
                                message: 'Erro buscando Visitas, nÃ£o achou resultados'

                            });
                        } else {
                            console.log("Dados"+results);
                            deferredDados.resolve( results );
                            //deferredDados.resolve( results.data] );
                        }

                    }

                });
          return deferredDados.promise;       
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!!

A member of my team found the error! \o/
Maybe this can help someone who will have the same problem.

To solve, you just have to convert the date, in string, to the date type.

The solved code is below:

```
.then(function (listaUsuarios){
       var argsVisit;


      if (tipoVisita == 'N'){
            argsVisit = {'user' : { "$in" :listaUsuarios }, 'tipo' : { "$in" : ["2001","2002"] }, "createdAt": {"$gte": dataInicial, "$lt": dataFinal }};
        } else if (tipoVisita == 'R'){
            argsVisit = {'user' : { "$in" :listaUsuarios }, 'tipo' : { "$in" : ["2005"] }, "createdAt": {"$gte": dataInicial, "$lt": dataFinal }};
        } else if (tipoVisita == 'I'){
            argsVisit = {'user' : { "$in" :listaUsuarios }, 'tipo' : { "$in" : ["2003"] }, "createdAt": {"$gte": dataInicial, "$lt": dataFinal }};
        }

        var initDate = new Date('2015-04-02T00:00:00.000Z');
        var endDate = new Date('2015-05-09T00:00:00.000Z');

       argsMatch = [{ $match : { "createdAt" : { $gte: initDate, $lt: endDate  }} },
                   { $group : { _id : { "usuario" : listaUsuarios , "dia" : { $dayOfMonth : "$createdAt" } },  "visitas" : {$sum : { $cond: [ {$or : [ { $eq: [ "$tipo", "2001"] },{ $eq: [ "$tipo","2002"] }] },1,0 ]}}}
                    }]

      Visita.aggregate(argsMatch)
        .exec(function (err, results) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Erro!!!");
                    deferredDados.reject({
                        error: 500,
                        message: 'Erro buscando Visita, erro: '+err
                    });
                } else {
                    if (!results || results.length == 0) {
                        console.log("Sem retorno!!!");
                        deferredDados.resolve( [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] ); //Tudo zerado poruqe nÃƒÂ£o hÃƒÂ¡ retorno.
                        //deferredDados.resolve(0);

                        deferredDados.reject({
                            error: 500,
                            message: 'Erro buscando Visitas, não achou resultados'

                        });
                    } else {
                        deferredDados.resolve( results );
                    }

                }

            });
      return deferredDados.promise;       
  })
  .then(function(dados) {
        res.json(dados);

    })
   .catch(function(fallback) {
    console.log('Erro no retorno dos usuarios!!!');
    console.log(fallback);
  });
```

I hope this can help someone.